# protractor leaves behind a chromedriver.exe

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor

I have some protractor tests running on windows 10. Every time I launch the tests, a new `chromedriver` gets started but it never goes away and keep piling up in the task manager. Why's that? Whom should I file the bug on? webdriver, protractor, or selenium?

This happens even with an empty config/test

Only `conf` I have is

```
exports.config = {
    framework: "jasmine",
    plugins: [],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
    },

    beforeLaunch: function() {
    },

    onPrepare: function() {
    },

    afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    },

    capabilities: { 
        "browserName": "chrome"
    },

    suites: {
        example: "spec.js",
    }
}
```

and the `spec.js` is essentially an empty test

called using `"test": "protractor tests/conf.js"` inside the package.json through npm

Comment: Successful launch of the tests through `chromedriver.exe` must be ended by destroying/killing of the `Browser Instance` as well as `chromedriver.exe` instance which is done programatically through invoking `quit()` method. Invoking `quit()` will help us from `chromedriver.exe` keeping pilled up in the Task Manager

Comment: Protractor handles quitting the driver itself, you should not need to explicitly quit the browser in the code - it will close and terminate chromedriver.exe itself when your test case is finished. Please can you provide more context on your setup. Also, are you using webdriver-manager or a path to a local executable?

Comment: at this point i commented out most of my setup and this still repro. i am using webdriver-manager. I just have a protractor config that is pretty much empty with an empty test. lll post my whole config when i get to a computer

Comment: @MatthewThomasGB i updated the question with the full config. And yes i am using webdriver-manager.

Comment: What versions are you using? I also noticed this too and wrote a fix for this. Probably was not tested on Windows.

Comment: @cnishina here are my dependencies 

    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "^4.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "protractor-fail-fast": "^3.0.2",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.3.5",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.0"

Comment: actual protractor version i have is 5.2.0 according to the lock file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a bat file with the commands to kill the chromedriver like below.

> @echo off
>
> taskkill /f /t /im chromedriver_2.38.exe
>
> exit

At the protractor.config.js I used the beforeLaunch() method and in each execution, it will verify if there's some chromedriver instantiated and I can use only one instance.

For execute the bat file I used child_process. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#

The code on protractor.config below:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

beforeLaunch() {
        exec('endchromedriver.bat');
}
```

Comment: ya i pretty much did the same but on gulp side. But this really should be fixed by webdriver/protractor

Comment: I am still facing this issue with chrome driver